# Surface mesh generation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mesh

I know how to use PDEtool in MATLAB. But now it is necessary for me to produce mesh on a surface.

Is there anyone who know how could I do this? Is it possible in MATLAB or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a mesh plot of your surface and you know the {X,Y,Z} of your surface, you can use **mesh** command in MATLAB to create mesh.
for example:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-8:.5:8); 
R = sqrt(X.^2 + Y.^2) + eps;
Z = sin(R)./R;
mesh(X,Y,Z,'EdgeColor','black')
```

If you want to use the mesh data for other reason, why don't you try [DistMesh](http://persson.berkeley.edu/distmesh/)?
it is briefly a simple mesh generator for MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but it's a combination of mesh-functions and I don't know how good the quality of the mesh is. Also I need the vertices and faces, so what i get is a little different than what you get when using `meshgrid`. However, it's still a mesh, isn't it?

1. Create surface mesh: `[FV.faces,FV.vertices] = isosurface(VOLUME);`
2. Quadruple the number of faces with [refinepatch](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16215-triangular-mesh-refinement/content/refinepatch.m) as many times as necessary: `FV = refinepatch(FV);`
3. Reduce the number of faces/vertices to `n`: `FV = reducepatch(FV,n);`

I'm also going to have a look at [iso2mesh](http://iso2mesh.sourceforge.net)

**Edit:**
With `vol2surf` from [iso2mesh](http://iso2mesh.sourceforge.net) I get a more regulary shaped mesh with less deviation (I used `plotmesh`from [iso2mesh](http://iso2mesh.sourceforge.net) to compare the meshes).